# How to obtain a certificate from a certified authority for Sitecore 9 Installation?

Tags: security, azure

I am planning to deployed Sitecore 9 Update 1 on Azure PaaS using Sitecore Marketplace template.

I have created the non-production environment like SIT,QA,UAT using self signed certificate option and its working fine.

**Sitecore recommendation:**

"For developer environments, you can generate a self-signed certificate using PowerShell. For production environments, you must obtain a certificate from a certified authority because of potential security concerns."

**Sitecore Client certificate requirement:**
"Sitecore requires a Base64-encoded blob of the authentication certificate in PKCS #12 format (.pfx) for service communications"

**My query is:**

We already have the SSL certificate for my domain's and sub domain in .PFX File. 
how we can obtain/generate the client certificate from SSL certificate, or is there any other way to obtain the client certificate?

When I provide the existing SSL certificate , it shows invalid certificate error

[image]

Which is known as we need to provide the client certificate? any ideas/suggestion/steps to obtain the client certificate for Sitecore 9 installation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to Sitecore

Comment: Isn't Client Certificate given by the same Certificate Authority?

Comment: @phani it should be, but I am not sure how to generate the client certificate

Answer (score 2):

When you make your Certificate Signing Request (CSR) which you send to the Certificate Authority, you designate in the request what the certificate will be used for.

In the case of a certificate already obtained, you need to regenerate a new CSR and get a new certificate from the CA. When making the CSR, designate that this is a Client Certificate.

Most CA's offer this as a reduced or free service on valid certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved by Sitecore team and updated on the azure marketplace version, now we can upload the existing SSL certificate at the time of installation through market place.

Previously the authorized SSL certificate was getting error at the time of uploading the certificate.

Comment: Mark this answer as accepted even it is your own :)